# Hyperlinks missing the http:// prefix render relative to the site and not as external links

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

The user has an option to enter hyperlinks which are persisted to the database, and then subsequently rendered to a Razor template. Where the user does not specify `http://`, however, the link is malformed; for example `www.test.com` renders as `http://ourdomain.com/www.test.com`.

How should we handle this?

Comment: How are you rendering the link?

Comment: This behavior is by design; that's a relative path that happens to look like a domain name

Comment: @NightOwl888 Using TinyMCE to take raw HTML, sanitizing against a blacklist, and persisting to the database. Then just displaying as plain text in Razor.

Comment: Please post the code you are using to render the link.

Comment: hey @NightOwl888 Thank you. My colleague is using the @MvcHtmlString.Create(Model.data) method. Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best thing to do is to run a regular expression on each hyperlink before you save it in the database. If it does not have `http://` or `https://` then I would just add `http://` in front. All https sites will redirect http to https but most sites that do not support https won't smoothly redirect https to http.

An example of a possible regex is:

`^(http|https)://`

You want to be careful to only replace the `http://` or `https://` thats at the verify beginning of the string in case those values are used in url parameters